# Split a string after a comma followed by any number

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a variable that outputs an address, such as: `Budapest, Mindegy utca, 1002 Hungary`. I don't need the number and '`Hungary`', only the first part.

So I'd like to split if there is a comma followed by any number.

The output of the address above should be: `Budapest, Mindegy utca`

This is what I tried to do:

```
addressVariable.split(', /\[[0-9]+\]/');
```

But it doesn't split the variable.

Comment: BTW, `', /\[[0-9]+\]/'` isn't a valid regex object, its a simple string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove the unwanted part:

```
'Budapest, Mindegy utca, 1002 Hungary'.replace(/,\s*\d+.*/, '')
// => "Budapest, Mindegy utca"
```

Comment: @TrisztánThar, You're welcome. Nice to help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just split your input according to the comma which inturn followed by zero or more spaces and digits and atlast print the index 0 to get the first value.

```
> "Budapest, Mindegy utca, 1002 Hungary".split(/,(?=\s*\d+)/)[0]
'Budapest, Mindegy utca'
```

OR

You could use `string.match` function.

```
> "Budapest, Mindegy utca, 1002 Hungary".match(/^.*?(?=,\s*\d+)/)[0]
'Budapest, Mindegy utca'
```

Answer (score 0):

To split a string after a comma followed by any number in javascript use:

```
result = text.split(/,(?=\s*\d)/);
```